# Help Centering the group

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=12cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\newcommand{\heart}{\ensuremath\heartsuit}
\newcommand{\butt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\heart}}

\newcommand*\wb[3]{%
  {\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{T1}{custom}{xl}{n}#3}}
  
  %{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}#3}}
 

% The page frame
\SetBgColor{Goldenrod3}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgContents{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0.5\paperwidth,0) {\wb{80}{34}{E}\rule[55pt]{.3\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
  \raisebox{50pt}{%
  \makebox[.4\textwidth]{\ \fontsize{24}{29}\selectfont\scshape Open Bar }}%
  \rule[55pt]{.3\textwidth}{0.4pt}\wb{80}{34}{F}};
\node at (2.4,-0.5\textheight) {\rule{0.4pt}{.82\textheight}};
\node at (19.1,-0.5\textheight) {\rule{0.4pt}{.82\textheight}};
\node at (0.5\paperwidth,-\textheight) {\wb{80}{80}{G}\rule[-10pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\wb{80}{34}{H}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

% colorize text
\newcommand*\ColText[1]
{\textcolor{Goldenrod3}{#1}}

% a tabular* for each food group
\newenvironment{Group}[1]
  {\centering{\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{.8\linewidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
    {\fontsize{24}{29}\selectfont\ColText{#1}}\\[0.8em]}
  {\end{tabular*}}}

% to format each entry
\newcommand*\Entry[2]{%

  \centering{\sffamily#1 & #2}}

% to format each subentry
\newcommand*\Expl[1]{%
  \centering{\hspace*{1em}\footnotesize #1}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}



    

\begin{Group}{Mixed Drink}
\Entry{Michelada}{} \\
\Expl{Beer, Clamato Juice, Lime Juice,} \\
\Entry{Palomas}{} \\
\Expl{Squirt and Tequila} \\
\Entry{Jack, Coke}{} \\
\Expl{Jack Daniels, Coca-Cola} \\
\Entry{Margarita}{} \\
\Expl{Tequila, Lime Juice, Orange liqueur, Kosher Salt, Tajin} \\


\end{Group}


\vspace{5mm}

\begin{Group}{\begin{center}
    {Beer}
\end{center}}
\Entry{Corona}{} \\ 
\Expl{} \\
\Entry{Modelo}{} \\ 
\Expl{} \\


\end{Group}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{Group}{\begin{center}
Non-Alcoholic    
\end{center}
}
\Entry{Water Bottle}{} \\ 
\Expl{} \\
\Entry{Coca-Cola}{} \\ 
\Expl{} \\
\Entry{Squirt}{} \\ 
\Expl{} \\
\Entry{Dr Perpper}{} \\ 
\Expl{} \\

Hello, I was trying to manipulate this file but I cannot get the gold text to the center. If anyone can let me know where to make changes in the code. I would appreciate it. I know there is other errors in there.


\end{Group}
\begin{center}
 \textbf{\heart Because no great story ever started with a salad.\heart}   
\end{center}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your code is not compilable. There's this compilation error  `Misplaced \crcr.`

Comment: Currently, you define 2 columns in your table but only really seem to use just 1 of them. Please clarify.

Comment: Will there be entries in which the contents of Expl need an automatic linebreak or would a regular `c` type column work as well?